# NGINX: 504 error after editing and rebuilding docker-compose

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have a server running with docker-compose that was running perfectly fine until I decided to mess with the nginx conf file.

I tried to add one line to increase the files I could upload

```
client_max_body_size 5M;
```

but even after reverting back the nginx container still returns `504 timeout`.

I can't understand what could be wrong as the only other thing I did was stop the containers and rebuild them after editing the nginx file.

I have reloaded and restarted my nginx service (though I don't actually know whether this is necessary when running in a docker container).

I have also exec'd into the docker container while running and the file has reverted back to its original but alas I'm still stuck with this pesky `504`.

Here is my nginx conf file for reference - any suggestions?

```
upstream prosebit {
  server prosebit:8000;
  # server localhost:8000;
}

# In case you want 'www' addresses to be automatically redirected without 'www'.
# server {
#   listen 80;
#   listen 443;
#   server_name www.threadlet.io;
#   return 301 https://threadlet.io$request_uri;
# }

server {
  listen 80;
  # removed default_server
  server_name myservername.com;
  #server_name example.com www.example.com;
  root /var/www/letsencrypt;

  location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    default_type "text/plain";

    try_files $uri =404;
  }

  location / {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  # removed default_server;
  server_name myservername.com;

  root /prosebit/prosebit/static;

  # client_max_body_size 10M;

  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers "thisisarealcipherinmyfile";
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
  ssl_session_timeout 5m;
  ssl_stapling on;
  ssl_stapling_verify on;
  resolver 8.8.8.8;
  resolver_timeout 5s;
  #add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains;";

  ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/dhparam.pem;
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/private/threadlet.io.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/threadlet.io.key;
  ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/ssl/private/threadlet.io.pem;

  try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html @prosebit;

  location @prosebit {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://prosebit;
  }
}
```

Comment: In your nginx.conf `client_max_body_size` is commented.

Comment: I'm showing the conf file after reverting back (I tested it uncommented, then commented it out)

Comment: You might wanna prune the volumes if you are okay to discard any changes. `docker volume prune`